# Add more than 1 worksheet in Excel with AppleScript

Tags: excel, applescript

The following AppleScript adds a new Worksheet to Microsoft Excel before Sheet1. Is there a possibility to specify how many worksheets I'd like to insert? In VBA, there is the `Count` parameter in the `Sheets.Add` method.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    make new worksheet at before sheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy method:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    repeat 5 times
        make new worksheet at before sheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
    end repeat
end tell
```

You can repeat as many times as needed.

Comment: OK thanks! - However, I was hoping for a method that invokes the loop on the side of Excel in order to be more efficient ;-)

Comment: @FelixZumstein I don't know any other method. I think what you're looking for is not a loop but a multiple create statement. As far as I know, this doesn't exist... :/